# A problem concerning compact operators in $\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\alpha_n \in \mathbb C$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n = 0$. Let $T$ be a linear continuous operator from $\ell^p \to \ell^p (1\le p\le \infty)$ defined by $$
T((x_1, x_2, \ldots)) = (\alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2 , \ldots).
$$
Then I want to show that $T$ is compact operator on $\ell^p$, which means any bounded sequence in $\ell^p$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{Tx_{n_k}\}$ converges in the sense of norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$(T_n(\underline x))_k:=\begin{cases}\alpha_kx_k&\text{if }k\le n\\ 0&\text{if }k>n\end{cases}$$

You can prove that $$\left\lVert T-T_n\right\rVert_{\mathfrak L(\ell^p,\ell^p)}\le \sup\{\lvert \alpha_k\rvert\,:\,k>n\}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$$

So $T$ is limit in $\mathfrak L(\ell^p,\ell^p)$ of finite-rank operators. Hence, it is compact.

Comment: Really appreciate to you. Now I got it